# Cannot access website from another computer on the same network

Tags: firewall, jupyter, intranet

This is odd to me:
I have jupyter notebook installed on a vm machine, it is working fine from localhost:8888/tree. The vm machine has an address of 192.168.112.150, I assume the site can be accessed from my desktop browser by typing: 192.168.112.150:8888/tree

I receive error saying:

> This site can’t be reached
>   192.168.112.150 took too long to respond.

I checked firewall settings on my desktop, it's opened; on the vm machine, I made some adjustment, here is the settings:

[image]

[image]

I have no problem ping the vm machine from my desktop
[image]

Can anyone enlighten me how to fix the issue? Thank you very much.

Updated: I receive this error message when I ran it with --ip=0.0.0.0

[image]

Comment: jupyter by default only binds to `localhost`/`127.0.0.1` if you launch it using something like: `jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8888 --ip=0.0.0.0` it should be accessible from your desktop.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, no change after I launched it your way, and the notebook is still only accessible to localhost, I updated the question to show the error message I received in the notebook server.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Jupyter Notebook only listens to incoming connections on localhost--it has zero permission checking or built-in safeguards otherwise. Adding `--ip=*` to the end of the command will have it listen on all of your network interfaces.

Comment: same error. here is my command to start the service: `jupyter notebook --port=8888 --ip=*`